# iPhone table cell label misaligned

Tags: iphone, uitableview, label, alignment

Similar to [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1770872/text-misalignment-on-tableview-cells-on-iphone-device), I am having a problem with text alignment in my table cells. All the text is shifted up by a few pixels. I am not using custom cells; I am using regular `UITableViewCell`s with the `UITableViewCellStyleValue1` style, targeting iPhone OS 3.1. I would prefer a much simpler solution than the previous question's answer, especially since I'm not using custom cells. I'd also like to know exactly what the problem *is*, since that part of the question was never addressed.

Here's what it looks like on the simulator:

[Simulator http://www.shaggyfrog.com/junk/table-cell-label-misalignment-simulator.png](http://www.shaggyfrog.com/junk/table-cell-label-misalignment-simulator.png)

And on the device:

[Device http://www.shaggyfrog.com/junk/table-cell-label-misalignment-device.png](http://www.shaggyfrog.com/junk/table-cell-label-misalignment-device.png)

Edit: some more code as per request. (I'm building my table cells outside of cellForRowAtIndexPath.)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return [cells objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self loadCells];
    [table reloadData];

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
}

- (void)loadCells
{
    cells = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:[self aCell], [self bCell], nil];
}

- (UITableViewCell*)aCell
{
    UITableViewCell* cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"Foo"] autorelease];
    cell.textLabel.text = @"A";
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    return cell;
}

- (UITableViewCell*)bCell
{
    UITableViewCell* cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"Foo"] autorelease];
    cell.textLabel.text = @"B";
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Could we see the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` code? I've used `UITableViewCellStyleValue1` without seeing this issue in the past.

Comment: Sure, I can add it, but I'm not sure how useful it will be.

Comment: I've never seen cells created like this before... they look OK though. Maybe something else in the code that you're not showing is the culprit?

Comment: Possibly. I've built cells like this before (including in this app) and have never seen this issue before. Like the previous question, it's as if the subviews are somehow misaligned, but by a tiny amount.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know your code says you are using cell style `UITableViewCellStyleValue1`, but the device screenshot really looks like `UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle`.

You should set a value for `cell.detailTextLabel.text` to make sure you are getting the expected cell style.

On that note, if you aren't going to use the `detailTextLabel` property, you should probably use `UITableViewCellStyleDefault`.

Comment: Oops -- you're right. That seems to have fixed it! I had those lines in there, but commented them out, and then accidentally removed those commented-out lines when I was anonymizing the code for posting here. In any case, thanks very much! This is definitely a bug with the layout algorithm.

Comment: Filed a bug report in Radar #7464950.

Comment: What's the layout bug? If you *were* using the Subtitle style, then the text was being laid out correctly.

Comment: I was not using the subtitle style, as per my code above. The layout bug is the textLabel is only properly aligned if the detailTextLabel has been set, but they should be independent of each other.

Comment: BTW - Can you comment on Apple's response?  I am curious about their explanation?  I looked for the RADAR #7464950, but it does not show up.

Comment: There's no response so far. The bug remains "Open". I don't think you can look up other people's bug reports -- I mostly just posted the # for completeness, so I apologize for misleading you there. :)

Comment: cooool! You saved me a lot. In some other posts, I saw ppl suggesting to create custom cells...

Comment: I forgot to update here: Apple said they have fixed the bug in iPhone OS 4.0.

Comment: Shaggy Frog: I'm at WWDC '10 and I flipped when I saw my cell.textLabel misaligned (when it was fine before). Your one comment just saved me a LOT of grief. Voted up. Thank you!