# Why is UITableViewCell text floating to top on the device?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview

The text lables in my UITableViewCells are getting displayed differently on the device than on the sim. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're running at most iPhone OS 3.1.2.

I [asked this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1883947/iphone-table-cell-label-misaligned) already. You are likely using the `UITableViewCellStyleValue1` style for your cells. The solution is to set `cell.detailTextLabel.text` to something other than nil.

I filed a bug a few months ago with Apple. I recently got an e-mail from Apple that said the bug should be fixed in the next SDK, but I haven't yet tested it.